# "In the reach of" or "in reach of"?

Tags: word-usage

Which one is better?

> For this reason, maximum power is not in reach of electromagnetic
> sources.

or

> For this reason, maximum power is not in the reach of electromagnetic
> sources.

The intended meaning is "For this reason, maximum power cannot be reached by electromagnetic sources."

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd be tempted to use "...is not achievable with electromagnetic sources."

Comment: IMO "*within* the reach of" would be the most idiomatic version for this context.

Comment: Thank you! So "within the reach of" is better than "within reach of"? Is there a way to explain this to a foreigner?

Comment: But I like "in reach of" better than "within the reach of".

Comment: "Within reach" is a set expression found in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/within%20reach) meaning "close enough to be achieved". That's not one of the OP's options, even though it's probably the best.